# Google webmaster tools site verification file in web2py?

Tags: web2py, google-search-console

To verify your site at google webmaster tools, you must download a verification file and upload it to your site to be available at:

`www.example.com/google1234a1ab1234a123.html`

Where should I put this file in the web2py directory structure?  I have a single web2py app that is served at www.example.com.  Note I am using pattern based routing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm open to better methods but I put the file in the static folder and added a routes_in entry:

```
routes_in = (
   ...
   ('/google1234a1ab1234a123.html', 
      r'/my_app/static/google1234a1ab1234a123.html'),
   ...
)
```

And now it's working.

Answer (score 0):

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21825558/440323) should work, though not if you are already using the parameter-based URL rewrite system (which is not compatible with the pattern-based system used in that answer). Instead, you might consider using one of the [three other methods](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/35179?hl=en) Google offers for verification, such as [setting a meta tag](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/35659).